# Ajax запрос зависает

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть форма регистрации, после ее заполнения и отправки начинает грузится ajax, то есть он заполняет бд, регестрируется, но ajax это не показывает, зависает, только если перезагрузить страницу он перейдет в страницу пользователя.

Вот код скрипта

```
$(".signup-form").ajaxForm({
    url: SK_source() + "?t=register",
    beforeSend: function() {
        signup_form = $(".signup-form"), signup_button = signup_form.find(".submit-btn"), signup_button.attr("disabled", !0), signup_form.find(".post-message").fadeOut("fast"), SK_progressIconLoader(signup_button)
    },
    success: function(e) {
        200 == e.status ? window.location = e.redirect_url : (signup_button.attr("disabled", !1), 0 == signup_form.find(".post-message").length ? signup_form.find(".signup-error-text").after('<div class="post-message hidden">' + e.error_message + "</div>").end().find(".post-message").fadeIn("fast") : signup_form.find(".post-message").html(e.error_message).fadeIn("fast")), SK_progressIconLoader(signup_button)
    }
})
```

а вот php обработчик

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете прикрепить код и перефразируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос...

Comment: При отправке ajax зависает, а php обрабатывает все. Там должен работать редирект, но не работает почему то

Comment: А что возвращает ajax запрос? Какие данные?

Comment: Ничего. Даже ошибки не выводит

Comment: @David Develop проверьте приходит ли в $_POST что-то

Comment: Дело в том что запрос идет нормально в POST приходят все вписанные данные, но ajax зависает после нажатия на кнопку отправить

Comment: @David Develop если у Вас в $_POST приходят данные, то ajax выполняется нормально. Я не могу понять почему вы думаете, что виснет ajax?

Comment: при удачной отправке там должен происходить редирект, он записан в js коде и php , но он просто зависает и не переходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему у Вас нету обработчика на error?
Возможно сервер не возвращает 200 ошибку.
Поэтому допишите еще колбек для error и смотрите в браузере ответ (chrome tools -> Network)

```
$(".signup-form").ajaxForm({
url: SK_source() + "?t=register",
beforeSend: function() {
    signup_form = $(".signup-form"), signup_button = signup_form.find(".submit-btn"), signup_button.attr("disabled", !0), signup_form.find(".post-message").fadeOut("fast"), SK_progressIconLoader(signup_button)
},
success: function(e) {
    200 == e.status ? window.location = e.redirect_url : (signup_button.attr("disabled", !1), 0 == signup_form.find(".post-message").length ? signup_form.find(".signup-error-text").after('<div class="post-message hidden">' + e.error_message + "</div>").end().find(".post-message").fadeIn("fast") : signup_form.find(".post-message").html(e.error_message).fadeIn("fast")), SK_progressIconLoader(signup_button)
},
error: function(e) { //смотрите здесь ошибку }
```

})